# Getting last tweet with PHP

Tags: php, twitter

To get my last tweet in PHP I use this code :

```
function getTweets($tweetsToDisplay, $user_id) { 

$twitterrequest = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=' . $user_id . '&include_rts=true&count=' . $tweetsToDisplay; 
$twitterci = curl_init($twitterrequest); 
curl_setopt($twitterci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$twitterinput = curl_exec($twitterci); 
curl_close($twitterci); 
return ($twitterinput); 

} 

$user_id = '99999999';
$var = json_decode(getTweets(1, $user_id));
$txt = $var[0]->text;
$txt = preg_replace('%(https?://)[^\s]*%', '$1...', $txt);
echo $txt;
```

Works fine but I want to get the date as well. How to extract it ?

Answer (score 7):

I hope code below help you.

```
function getTimeline($count, $username) {
   $url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='.$username.'&count=.'$count;
   $tweets = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),TRUE);

   return $tweets;
}
```

Comment: There's a bug in this code, also twitter no longer support V1 API

Comment: Bug isn't exist, because `answered Jun 20 '11 at 20:23`

PS But this code really don't worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simple PHP function that I created to catch latest tweets easily (does not require API authentication). Must be optimized :)

```
function getTweets($user, $count) {
    $datas = file_get_contents('https://twitter.com/'.$user);

    preg_match_all('/<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">(.*?)<\/p>/', $datas, $matchetweets);
    $matchetweets[1] = preg_replace('/<s>(.?)<\/s>/', '$1', $matchetweets[1]);
    $matchetweets[1] = preg_replace('/(class|dir|rel|data-expanded-url|data-pre-embedded|data-query-source)="(.*?)"/', '', $matchetweets[1]);
    $matchetweets[1] = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $matchetweets[1]);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        echo '<li>'.$matchetweets[1][$i].'</li>'."\n";
    }
};
```

Usage

```
echo getTweets('nasa', 3);
```

**UPDATE (10/15/2014) :**

This version is out of date and not working anymore. Here is an updated PHP code to parse tweets easily.

```
function getTweets($user, $count) {
    $datas = file_get_contents('https://mobile.twitter.com/'.$user);

    preg_match_all('/<div class="tweet-text" data-id="\d*">(.*?)<\/div>/', $datas, $matchetweets);
    $matchetweets[1] = preg_replace('/<div class="dir-ltr" dir="ltr">/', '', $matchetweets[1]);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        echo '<li>'.$matchetweets[1][$i].'</li>'."\n";
    }
};
```

**UPDATE (5/30/2015) :**

```
function getTweets($user, $count) {
    $datas = file_get_contents('https://mobile.twitter.com/'.$user);

    preg_match_all('/<div class="tweet-text" data-id="\d*">(.*?)<\/div>/s', $datas, $matchetweets, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $matchetweets[$i][0] = preg_replace('/<div class="dir-ltr" dir="ltr">/', '', $matchetweets[$i][0]);
        $matchetweets[$i][0] = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $matchetweets[$i][0]);
        $matchetweets[$i][0] = str_replace('"> ', '">', $matchetweets[$i][0]);

        echo '<li>'.$matchetweets[$i][0].'</li>'."\n";
    }
};
```

Usage doesn't change. Minimum 1 tweet, maximum 20 tweets.

Comment: For some reason, this does not get the latest tweet. Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it.. Had to change the starting value in the for-loop from 1 to 0

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date = $var[0]->created_at;
```

That should work!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to bottom of your code.

```
$time = $var[0]->created_at;
echo $time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Twitter API results from http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline, it appears that you could use the `created_at` param.

You have:

```
$txt = $var[0]->text;
```

If that works then add

```
$created = $vars[0]->created_at;

echo $txt;
echo "<span>".$created."</span>" ;
```